# Not sure why this basic watchOS 2 app isn't working

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, wkinterfacelabel

This is the first day I am learning how to code. I want to make a simple WatchKit App using watchOS 2.

I got the Hello World app up and running and now when I try to have a menu press trigger a label to change, the code won't compile, with the following error:

> WKInterfaceLabel doesn't have a member called set.

You can see the detailed image [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tjw5csqqk2c4k2/Screenshot%202015-08-08%2020.58.35.png?dl=0).

Swift Code:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }


    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    @IBAction func CookBabyCook() {
        label.set("Cooked!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Label.set()` is the problem here.

I believe the label object doesn't have a `set()` method. You must replace it with `setText()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliver!  That worked out, much appreciated :)